# How to using class variable without initializing value?

Tags: typescript

```
class testClass
{
    student: {
        name: string,
        age: number
    }

    constructor(options?: any) {
        // initialize default values
        this.student = {
            name='',
            age=0
        };
    }

    setStudent(name:string, age:number) {
        this.student.name = name; //
        this.studetn.age = age;
    }

}
```

If I remove the initialize default value code in constructor method, **undefined error** will be occurred on setting line.

But the initializing codes are looks ugly and I don't think this is right approach.

How should I do to make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do at the point of `declaration`:

```
class TestClass {
    student: {
        name: string,
        age: number
    } = {
        name: '',
        age: 0
    }

    constructor(options?: any) {
    }

    setStudent(name: string, age: number) {
        this.student.name = name;
        this.student.age = age;
    }

}
```

In fact you don't even need to provide the type annotation as it can be inferred:

```
class TestClass {
    student = {
        name: '',
        age: 0
    }

    constructor(options?: any) {
    }

    setStudent(name: string, age: number) {
        this.student.name = name;
        this.student.age = age;
    }
}
```

## More

This is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html